# Get column and row of count from GridLayoutGroup programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel with `GridLayoutGroup` on it.
Constraint is set to "Flexible" so it is not fixed in row and column and i don't want it to be.

Now I want get the column count for this `GridLayout` in code behind, and then change the size of cells to fit on screen.

[image]

```
 GridLayoutGroup layoutgroup;
```

I have the GridLayoutGroup variable in my code, but there is no function to get columns of it.

how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to count them manually in a loop. You can get the column and row count from the `GridLayoutGroup` component by doing the following:

**1**.Get the position of the first child of the Object under the `GridLayoutGroup` object. The position should be from `RectTransform.anchoredPosition` which returns `Vector2`.

**2**.Loop from the second child to the rest of the child objects of the `GridLayoutGroup`.

**3**.In each loop from **#2**, compare the `x` component from the first child against the `x` component from the current loop.

Create a boolean variable outside the loop that determines when to stop counting the row. The fault value should be `false`.

If the `x` values match, it's a **column**, so increment column by `1` then set the boolean variable to `true`.

If the `x` values are not the-same, and the boolean variable is `false`, it's a **row**, so increment row by `1`.

Basically, you stop counting or incrementing row when column is found in the loop. That's what the boolean variable is used for.

```
void GetColumnAndRow(GridLayoutGroup glg, out int column, out int row)
{
    column = 0;
    row = 0;

    if (glg.transform.childCount == 0)
        return;

    //Column and row are now 1
    column = 1;
    row = 1;

    //Get the first child GameObject of the GridLayoutGroup
    RectTransform firstChildObj = glg.transform.
        GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    Vector2 firstChildPos = firstChildObj.anchoredPosition;
    bool stopCountingRow = false;

    //Loop through the rest of the child object
    for (int i = 1; i < glg.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        //Get the next child
        RectTransform currentChildObj = glg.transform.
       GetChild(i).GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        Vector2 currentChildPos = currentChildObj.anchoredPosition;

        //if first child.x == otherchild.x, it is a column, ele it's a row
        if (firstChildPos.x == currentChildPos.x)
        {
            column++;
            //Stop couting row once we find column
            stopCountingRow = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!stopCountingRow)
                row++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public GridLayoutGroup gridLG;

void Update()
{
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    GetColumnAndRow(gridLG, out column, out row);
    Debug.Log("Column: " + column + "   Row: " + row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to iterate through all the children.
Finding the rightmost element of the first row will be enough.

Usage example:

```
var grid = GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
Vector2Int size = grid.Size();
```

Helper class:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public static class GridLayoutGroupHelper
{
    public static Vector2Int Size(this GridLayoutGroup grid)
    {
        int itemsCount = grid.transform.childCount;
        Vector2Int size = Vector2Int.zero;

        if (itemsCount == 0)
            return size;

        switch (grid.constraint)
        {
            case GridLayoutGroup.Constraint.FixedColumnCount:
                size.x = grid.constraintCount;
                size.y = getAnotherAxisCount(itemsCount, size.x);
                break;

            case GridLayoutGroup.Constraint.FixedRowCount:
                size.y = grid.constraintCount;
                size.x = getAnotherAxisCount(itemsCount, size.y);
                break;

            case GridLayoutGroup.Constraint.Flexible:
                size = flexibleSize(grid);
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Unexpected constraint: {grid.constraint}");
        }

        return size;
    }

    private static Vector2Int flexibleSize(this GridLayoutGroup grid)
    {
        int itemsCount = grid.transform.childCount;
        float prevX = float.NegativeInfinity;
        int xCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            Vector2 pos = ((RectTransform)grid.transform.GetChild(i)).anchoredPosition;

            if (pos.x <= prevX)
                break;

            prevX = pos.x;
            xCount++;
        }

        int yCount = getAnotherAxisCount(itemsCount, xCount);
        return new Vector2Int(xCount, yCount);
    }

    private static int getAnotherAxisCount(int totalCount, int axisCount)
    {
        return totalCount / axisCount + Mathf.Min(1, totalCount % axisCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with localPosition of the children.

```
void CountColumnsAndRow()
    {
        Vector3 firstElementPosition = m_UpgradePanel.transform.GetChild(0).localPosition;
        foreach(Transform t in m_UpgradePanel.transform)
        {
            if (Mathf.Approximately(firstElementPosition.y, t.localPosition.y))
                m_NumOfCol++;
            else break;
        }

        m_NumOfRow = 1;
        foreach (Transform t in m_UpgradePanel.transform)
        {
            if(!Mathf.Approximately(firstElementPosition.y, t.localPosition.y))
            {
                m_NumOfRow++;
                firstElementPosition = t.localPosition;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("RowNumber:" + m_NumOfRow + " ColumnNumber:" + m_NumOfCol);

    }
```